# Get informations from mouse

Tags: c

I'm doing my own FTP in C with ncurses. I know it's possible to get information like coord of click ... with the function `getch()`. My problem is for this school subject I can't use this function.

I would like to know if it's possible to get information like coord click, position, with button is used ... from the mouse in a terminal with read?

If it's possible with file descriptor I have to read?

Else with call system can do it?

I'm on sierra :)

**Update**

Yes I have a piece of code to get values

for example :

```
mouse click left down : 27, 91, 77, 32, 57, 67, 0, 0, 0
mouse click left up   : 27, 91, 77, 35, 57, 67, 0, 0, 0
```

Like you can see I get 6 bytes for all events.
I understand byte[0] until byte[3] but I don't know what the byte 4 and 5 mean ... They look like random :(

Values are print in decimal

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is for this school subject i can't use this function.

Then you're out of luck. `curses` provides this for a reason: it abstracts the many platform-dependent ways how to get mouse input. If you can't use what `curses` provides, you have to write code specifically for your target platform, which doesn't make any sense if you already use `curses`.